# Query in URL not affecting view filters

Tags: 7, database, views, uri

I currently have a view that has a page display and a block display. The page is disabled, but I have exposed the form in a block, which is then displayed on the homepage of the site.

When the user selects the filters and submits, it then goes to another page with the results in the block view (filters included).

The problem I'm facing is that when the user submits the form from the homepage, the results aren't showing on the subsequent page. The query shows in the URL but it doesn't change the results.

This was working before, but has suddenly stopped working. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: Turns out that there was a feature module created for a mini panel that was breaking this. I've removed this mini panel for now, and it's fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a common mistake with views.

On you filter's settings, under More make sure you have the Filter identifier set with the same name, in both your page and your block.

Comment: Just checked this out, they're all sharing the same respective filter identifiers, I don't think I would've changed these to begin with.